# Unable to locate the specified class: Security.php

Tags: error

I've just started to install expression engine 2.8.1 (for the record I experienced the exact same problem with version 2.7.3) I've installed expression engine god knows how many times and have 6 copies of expression engine on the same server but when I go to run the installer I am experiencing the error

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Security.php
```

Has anyone experienced this before and if so, what was the fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little research and a bit of asking around on forums, I found that GoDaddy shared servers were reading the contents of the Security.php file and treating it as malware.

I've got in touch with GoDaddy and I'm waiting on a response but this is another reason for me to take my hosting elsewhere...

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/244598/

Comment: Yeah, apparently GoDaddy is attempting to detect malware by doing some keyword scans, but it appears to only be when [uploading files via FTP](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/244487/#1064479). Happens with WordPress too or really any file with certain words in it. One solution mentioned in the forum is to create the file via GoDaddy's cPanel.